# Listen to click events on elements that aren't appended

Tags: javascript

I want to listen to click events on elements that are dynamically created and aren't appended. See this example:

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  if(e.target.tagName == 'BUTTON'){
    console.log('Click');
  }
});
document.createElement('button').click();
```

```html
<button>Test</button>
```

The listener isn't called when creating an element and using the click method on  it.

Why is this and how can I listen to those events?

Thanks!

Comment: Because you haven't inserted the new element in the document anywhere. It only exists in memory

Comment: So how can I listen to events of elements that aren't inserted?

Comment: Would need to add a listener to that new element itself. Why do you need to trigger a click on it in the first place?

Comment: I'm trying to make a userscript that detects click events on dynamically created elements.

Comment: Well you wouldn't be triggering a click on elements before they are inserted in document would you?

Comment: I wouldn't but alot of websites do. Would it be possible by overwriting HTMLElement.click()?

Comment: Only use case for triggering an event on an element outside the document that I can think of is for an ajax download that clicks on a new `<a download>`. Beyond that not really sure what you men by *"alot of websites do"*

Comment: I'm just trying to cover all corner cases. So it's not posible to listen to events from elements outside of the DOM without adding listeners to them individually?

Comment: Basically...yes

Comment: Thanks, I'll try overwriting HTMLElement.click() then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, either overwrite `HTMLButtonElement.prototype.click`:

```js
const nativeClick = HTMLButtonElement.prototype.click;
HTMLButtonElement.prototype.click = function(...args) {
  console.log('Click');
  nativeClick.apply(this, args);
};

document.createElement('button').click();
```

Or, a slightly different (and less efficient) method would be to overwrite `Document.prototype.createElement` such that newly created `button`s get listeners attached to them:

```js
const nativeCreateElement = Document.prototype.createElement;
Document.prototype.createElement = function(...args) {
  const createdElement = nativeCreateElement.apply(this, args);
  if (typeof args[0] === 'string' && args[0].toLowerCase() === 'button') {
    createdElement.addEventListener('click', () => {
      console.log('Click');
    });
  }
  return createdElement;
}

document.createElement('button').click();
```

Note that overwriting important built-in objects and methods like this is *very hacky* and isn't something to be used in serious production code - it's only something to consider when you have no other options, such as in the unusual environment of a userscript.

Comment: Thanks! My question was marked as duplicate at first by someone who didn't fully read it. It's for a userscript so that's fine. By the way it should work on all elements not just buttons. The button was just for the example.